# MySQL syntax error in my code that I can't find manually

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

Joining two tables to get correct information and update one value from one table by conditioning with some specific conditions

SQL say that it has syntax error at line 5 although it didn't fix the syntax error automatically if he (SQL) knew that

```
UPDATE
  sale
SET
  amount = 10000
FROM
  sale
  JOIN delivery ON delivery.sale_id = sale.id
WHERE
  sale.`status` = "active"
  AND delivery.services_id = 7;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around:
>   'FROM sale JOIN delivery ON delivery.sale_id = sale.id WHERE
>   sale.`status` ' at line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support UPDATE ... FROM (that is a SQL Server feature)

Here is the reference to mySQL update syntax:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for a MySQL multi-table update ([manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)) puts the table references at the beginning of the query:

```
UPDATE
  sale
  JOIN delivery ON delivery.sale_id = sale.id
SET
  amount = 10000
WHERE
  sale.`status` = "active"
  AND delivery.services_id = 7;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ff1a56c06b0a6f86938391095e906668)

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you accepted the other answer instead of the one that gave you an actual working solution?